# strace/ltrace outputs inconsistent info

Tags: strace, ptrace, ltrace

`strace pwd`:

```
getcwd("/root"..., 4096)                = 6
```

`ltrace pwd`:

```
getcwd(NULL, 0)                                     = "/root"
```

Why the 1st parameter is `NULL` in `ltrace`?

It eems strace/ltrace both uses the `ptrace` syscall,but why they get different info?

Answer (score 4):

Right, they both use `ptrace`, and also they get different info. This is because they use `ptrace` differently.

If you have a look at the [ptrace man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace), you will see that there exist several 'request' values, which decide the behaviour of ptrace.

More concretely, if you use `ptrace` to previously set the option `PTRACE_O_TRACESYSGOOD`, you have a way to distinguish between the traps leading to system calls and the traps that are not leading to system calls.

Answer (score 3):

`ltrace` shows the library call.  In this case, it shows the function from the `libc` that the source code is calling.

If you see `pwd`'s source, you will see (coreutils-8.13, file lib/xgetcwd.c):

```
char *cwd = getcwd (NULL, 0);
```

So, `ltrace`'s output is correct: `pwd` executes `getcwd(NULL, 0)`.  According to the Linux man page `getcwd(3)`:

> getcwd() allocates the buffer dynamically using malloc(3) if buf is NULL.

However, the system call `getcwd(2)` always needs a first argument different from NULL, to copy there the pathname.  You can see how this is done in the libc source (eglibc-3.13, file sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/getcwd.c).

The library call `getcwd(NULL, 0)` executes the system call `getcwd(path, alloc_size)`, where `path` is the result of a previous malloc(), and `alloc_size` is the page size (4096).

To confirm this, if you run `ltrace -S pwd` you will see both the library calls and the system calls: you will see something like:

```
getcwd(NULL, 0 <unfinished ...>
SYS_getcwd("/root", 4096)                        = 6
<... getcwd resumed> )                           = "/root"
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the system call and the library call are different. Read the manpage for the getcwd function and you'll see that it has the following prototype:

```
long getcwd(char *buf, unsigned long size);
```

Comment: @zvrba,why do you think this answers my question?

Comment: Because the manpage also explains that passing NULL is a linux extension. And it might also be a bug in ltrace. Impossible to know w/o seeing the code.

Comment: ptrace() knows absolutely nothing about parameters. function/syscall arguments and how they should be interpreted are hard-coded into strace and ltrace.

Comment: @zvrba ,what's the most important bit of code control that makes strace/ltrace have different feature?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking there. Which feature? strace hooks into the system call mechanism, ltrace modifies entry points of dynamic library functions.

Comment: @zvrba,can you explain brieftly how it's done with `ptrace`,say , `hooks into the system call mechanism` and  `modifies entry points of dynamic library functions`?

Comment: It cannot be explained "briefly". Read the ptrace manpage, ELF documentation, Linux ABI documentation and the source for strace and ltrace.